# Asynchronous signals with asyncio

Tags: django, signals, python-asyncio

My model post processing is using the `post_save` signal:

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.dispatch import receiver
from models import MyModel
from pipeline import this_takes_forever


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    this_takes_forever(sender)
```

The `this_takes_forever` routine does IO so I want to defer it to avoid blocking the request too much.

I thought this was a great use case for the new [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module. But I have a hard time getting my mind around the whole process.

I think I should be able to adapt the signal receiver like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(this_takes_forever(sender))
    loop.close()
```

Provided `this_takes_forever` is also adapted to be a coroutine.

```
@coroutine
def this_takes_forever(instance):
    # do something with instance
    return instance
```

This sounds too magical to work. And in fact it halts with an `AssertionError`:

```
AssertionError at /new/
There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

I don't see where should I start the loop in this context. Anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 6):

You get no any benefit in your case:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    this_takes_forever(sender)
```

is equal to

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(this_takes_forever(sender))
    loop.close()
```

in terms of execution time. `loop.run_until_complete` waits for end of `this_takes_forever(sender)` coroutine call, so you get synchronous call in second case as well as in former one.

About `AssertionError`: you start Django app in multithreaded mode, but `asyncio` makes default event loop for main thread only -- you should to register new loop for every user-created thread where you need to call asyncio code.

But, say again, asyncio cannot solve your particular problem, it just incompatible with Django.

The standard way for Django is to defer long-running code into celery task (see http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: Ok with the first point. Maybe this is just a bad example, I'll try to refactor for more clarity.

Anyway I'm not using django in any multithreaded mode, just running the default `runserver` which is one thread. Looking deeper seems like I'd need to wire some non-blocking server like [aiohttp](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp)

Comment: From my understanding `runserver` actually creates new thread to run Django app inside it by default -- that is how `autoreload` feature works.

Comment: about aiohttp -- please note the library is too low level now comparing Django or, say, tornado.web.
I'm working on more user friendly interface but the work is in very early stage.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly. I'm talking about running django with aiohttp instead of the builtin runserver, [look here](https://github.com/aaugustin/django-c10k-demo/blob/master/c10ktools/monkey.py).